# Recover unidentified free space after erase

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I am having problem dealing with this situation:
after I deleted a system that I don't want via eraseVolume, I don't have the access to this 119.4 GB space below. I have no idea how to recover it, even with disk drill. Now all I want it to be is at where the Macintosh HD is at and make it a part of the main partition. I have the `diskutil list` output below and the `sudo gpt -r show disk0` output.[image]

[image: image 1]

Comment: Please replace the images with pasted text in a code block. The text in images is not searchable. See [How do I format my posts?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Can I assume `Macintosh HD` is in `disk0s2`?

Answer (score 0):

Note the following:

- This answer assumes the `Macintosh HD` volume is in `disk0s2` container.
- I believe the latest version of macOS no longer allows the `gpt` command to change the GPT. Therefore, this answer will use the free third party tool `gdisk` to change the GPT. See [here](https://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) for more information.

In order to use the `diskutil` command to add the 119.4 GB of free space to the `disk0s2` container, there can be no partitions between the free space and `disk0s2`. Since the 29,140,265 sectors of free space is larger than the 25,643,520 sectors occupied by `disk0s3` through `disk0s6`, you could use `gdisk` to create partitions of the same same as `disk0s3` through `disk0s6` in the free space, then use the `dd` command to copy the data to the new partitions. Afterwards, you could use `gdisk` to remove the older partitions. Note that `gdisk` would need to be run in Recovery mode.

Once the partitions have been duplicated, you can use the following command to add the free space to `disk0s2`.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```